# Is it possible to have a ListView generate side by side boxes?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the image below. I'm pulling some data from Firebase to generate the content. Is this possible to achieve with a `ListView` or am I better off trying to slap something together using `Columns`, `Rows`, and some functions? I already have the skeleton for design purposes done. But, just curious if you can do this with a ListView or something similar somehow?

I've tried searching and couldn't really find a good answer.

[image]

Comment: you can try the Wrap widget

Comment: I don't think this is doable with a `ListView` due to the uneven heights between two side-by-side widgets. You're probably better off using a `Row` with two `Column`s in a `SingleChildScrollView`, or a `Wrap`,